# Trouble getting contact folders through microsoft graph api

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm having difficulties getting Microsoft Graph to return two test Contact Folders that I have set up named `Test` and `Test 2`.

When I use v1.0:

```python
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders'
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
response_data = response.json()
print(response_data)
```

I get a blank value in the response:

```js
{
    '@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('jacobdansey%40hotmail.com')/contactFolders",
    'value': []
}
```

When I use the Beta, I get this which at least returns something but not what I'm looking for:

```js
{
    '@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('jacobdansey%40hotmail.com')/contactFolders",
    'value': [{
        'id': '*ID*',
        'parentFolderId': '*ParentID*',
        'displayName': 'Contacts',
        'wellKnownName': 'contacts'
    }, {
        'id': '*ID*',
        'parentFolderId': '*ParentID*',
        'displayName': 'Skype Contacts',
        'wellKnownName': 'skypecontacts'
    }]
}
```

I know I am connecting properly because when I ask for just contacts from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts`, it returns the correct answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Is there a difference between contact folders and contact lists?

Comment: Hmm it looks like maybe there's something odd with your account. You're making the right calls but your data isn't right. If you could post the response headers from one of these calls I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure you created new Contact Folders and not new Contact Lists?

Comment: Not sure, I think I actually created a contact list? I was looking it up for outlook.com and couldn't tell the difference

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you want access to folder to get the contacts, if thats the case then you can directly get the contacts of that folder changing the get url

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts

Comment: The reason I am asking for the folders first is because the user is selecting the contact folder that they want to get the contacts for. So I want to get the contact folders, then do another call to get the contacts of the contact folder that the user chose.

Comment: may be this might help https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/mailfolder_list_childfolders.md